# Issue with calling JavaScript interface function in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I am encountering a peculiar issue with calling JavaScript interface functions in my Android WebView. I have defined a JavaScript interface class as follows:

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {
    Context mContext;

    JavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void playSound(int id) {
        // Implementation for playSound method
        doPlay(id);
    }

    @JavascriptInterface
    public void Amir(int id) {
        // Implementation for Amir method
        doPlay(id);
    }
}
```

I can execute these functions through the WebView using the following code:

```
Android.playSound(12);
```

The issue arises when I change the code to call the Amir function like so:

```
Android.Amir(12);
```

This results in an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Android.Amir is not a function
```

I have ensured that the Amir function is correctly defined within the JavaScriptInterface class. Could someone please help me identify the potential cause of this problem and suggest a solution? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the error?

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Android.Amir is not a function` but no problem with `Android.playSound(12);`

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code where you call `addJavascriptInterface(..)`? Also the error message from the last comment should be included in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Android studio and after restarting it and making project problem solved.